# Batch copy objects

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to perform bulk rename objects in a AWS S3 bucket in a Java standalone application. Apparently there is only copy and delete APIs supported.
I am using the same , but using them as separate API call is pretty slow. 
Batch delete API is pretty much in AWS documentation
Could not find batch copy method. any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

OS : Mac
Language: Java (any version preferably 11)
AWS version: Any

Comment: There is no bulk copy, yes, but did you try this way? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingLLJavaMPUapi.html It might be faster.

Comment: @ram That is for large files >5Gb, in my case the files are of smaller size but too many files to rename

Comment: 5gb is the upper limit for each part. You can have smaller parts.

Comment: Ru sure? "To copy an Amazon S3 object that is larger than 5 GB with the AWS SDK for Java, use the low-level Java API . For objects smaller than 5 GB, use the single-operation copy described in Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for Java."

Comment: It doesn’t prevent you from using smaller parts. As I said, 5gb is upper limit. You *must* copy part by part when it is larger, but *can* do also with smaller parts, where lower limit is 5mb.

Comment: ok , I am not sure if will be useful, I will give it a try. the reason I say is , the network latency for each request seems to be around 500ms. Even if I use multipart API, I am not sure it will help me. I need to make fewer server calls and perform bulk/batch operations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198621/discussion-between-ravisha-and-ram).

Comment: Check [S3 batch operations](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/).